Angular login and http-interceptor - runtime problem
I use this function to login:
login() {
  this.authService.login(this.ngForm.value).subscribe({
  next: (response) => {
  const loginData = response;
  this.user = loginData.user;
  this.authService.setToken(loginData.token);
  this.authService.setUser(loginData.user);
  this.route.navigateByUrl('app/tabs/tab1');
},
error: (error) => {
 ...
},
complete: () => {
  const self = this;
  setTimeout(function() { // needed because otherwise x-auth-token is not set in app-http-interceptor
    self.getHighestUserRole();
  },0);
  }
 });
}

without the setTimeout function I have to press the login button twice in order to get logged in because at first time I press it this.authService.getToken() (token) is still null:
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return from(this.authService.getToken()).pipe(
        switchMap((token) => {
            const tokenString: string = token as string;
            if(token) {
                if(this.noHeaderNeeded(req.url)) {
                    let authReq = req.clone({
                        setHeaders: {  
                            'x-auth-token': tokenString,
                            }
                    });
                    return next.handle(authReq);
                } else {
                    let authReq = req.clone({
                        setHeaders: {  
                            'x-auth-token': tokenString,
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            }
                    });
                    return next.handle(authReq);
                }
            } else {
                return next.handle(req);
            } 
        })
    );
}

setToken and getToken looks like this:
setToken(token: string) {
  this._storage?.set(AuthService.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, token);
}

getToken(): any {
  const userKey = this.storage.get(AuthService.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY);
  return userKey;
}

setHighestUserRoleTypeEnum and getHighestUserRoleTypeEnum looks like this:
setHighestUserRoleTypeEnum(userRole: UserRoleEnum) {
  this._storage?.set(AuthService.HIGHEST_USER_ROLE_KEY, userRole);
}

getHighestUserRoleTypeEnum(): any {
  const highestUserRole = this.storage.get(AuthService.HIGHEST_USER_ROLE_KEY);
  return highestUserRole;
}

Is there a better way to do it instead of setTimeout?

please share the full interceptor code and also getHighestUserRole code

Why not use a BehaviorSubject? It will ensure that the interceptor will receive the token value whenever it is available, eliminating the need for the delay introduced by setTimeout.
private tokenSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string | null>(null);

setToken(token: string) {
  this._storage?.set(AuthService.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, token);
  this.tokenSubject.next(token);
}

getToken(): Observable<string | null> {
  return this.tokenSubject.asObservable();
}


Also try an alternative approach of .
return from(this.storage.get(AuthService.HIGHEST_USER_ROLE_KEY)).pipe( 
    ...

Could you try using of instead of from, maybe that is the problem.
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return of(this.authService.getToken()).pipe( // <- changed here!
        switchMap((token) => {
            const tokenString: string = token as string;
            if(token) {
                if(this.noHeaderNeeded(req.url)) {
                    let authReq = req.clone({
                        setHeaders: {  
                            'x-auth-token': tokenString,
                            }
                    });
                    return next.handle(authReq);
                } else {
                    let authReq = req.clone({
                        setHeaders: {  
                            'x-auth-token': tokenString,
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            }
                    });
                    return next.handle(authReq);
                }
            } else {
                return next.handle(req);
            } 
        })
    );
}

